# How to convert type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<Object?>?'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I want to get the data from Firebase in streambuilder. How to convert the Future into Stream.

Below is my code.

```
getData() async {
    var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    await db.collection('categories').doc(value).get().then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
      var listSubCol = doc["categoryCollection"];
      listSubCol.forEach((id) {
        db.collection('categories').doc(value).collection(id).get().then((snapshot) {
          snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
            items.add(element.data());
          });
        });
        return items;
      });
    });
    return items;
  }
```

```
StreamBuilder(
                    stream: getData(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context,snapshot){
                      print('snap: ${items.length}');
                      if(!snapshot.hasData){
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      }else{
                        return Container(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: items.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, int index){
                              return Text(items[index]['categoryName']);
                              },
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    }
                ),
```

can anyone please help me on this issue.

Comment: If I am not mistaken you can use getDate().asStream()

Comment: Or use a StreamController as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63168022/flutter-convert-future-to-stream

Comment: Thanks @DEFL. 
Now i am having another issue, when i try to print the value in console, i am getting null value initially for this statement print('snap: ${snapshot.data}');
I dont know where i am making the mistake.

Comment: Change the type of you StreamBuilder. Use StreamBuilder<Future<dynamic> (ot the type of your object)

Comment: Never create the Stream in the stream: parameter of a StreamBuilder! `stream: getData()` is broken.  Instead, create the stream in initState and store it in a state variable, and reference that variable in the StreamBuilder.  See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg for a demonstration.